# Multidimensional html input array create in php, and post

Tags: php, html, forms, multidimensional-array

```
while($eredmeny = mssql_fetch_assoc($result))
{   
$table_results  = '<tr style="color: #000e94; font-size=12" align="center" valign="middle">';
$table_results .= '<td>';
$table_results .= "<input type='checkbox' name='form[][id]' id='form[][id]' value='{$eredmeny['ID']}'>"; 
$table_results .= '</td>';
$table_results .= '<td><input type="text" name="form[][idnap]" id="form[][idnap]" value="' . $eredmeny['ID'] .'" style="width:130px;"></td>';   
$table_results .= '<td><input type="text" name="form[][feladat]" id="form[][feladat]" value="' . $eredmeny['Feladat'] .'" style="width:130px;"></DIV></td>';
$table_results .= '<td><b><input type="text" name="form[][hatarnap]" id="form[][hatarnap]" value="' . date_format(date_create($eredmeny['Hatarido_alap']), 'd') .'" style="width:20px;">nap</b>';
$table_results .= '<input type="text" name="form[][hatarora]" id="form[][hatarora]" value="' . date_format(date_create($eredmeny['Hatarido_alap']), 'H:i:s') . '" style="width:55px;"></td>';
$table_results .= '<td>' . $eredmeny['Tipusa'] . '</td>';
$table_results .= '</tr>';
echo $table_results;
}
```

I've this code, to create html form. The form is usabe, good. I've got this form in php:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => NAPI_01_
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [idnap] => NAPI_01_20140220
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [feladat] => SM1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [hatarnap] => 01
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [hatarora] => 07:15:00
```

I need an array similar, but I don't know how now.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => NAPI_01_
            [idnap] => NAPI_01_20140220
            [feladat] => SM1
            [hatarnap] => 01
            [hatarora] => 07:15:00
        )
[1] => Array
        (
            [id] => NAPI_01_
            [idnap] => NAPI_01_20140220
            [feladat] => sm2
            [hatarnap] => 01
            [hatarora] => 07:15:00
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting each form input as a separate element in the main array is because of this: `name="form[][idnap]"`. You create a new item in your main array with `[]`, then add an array key to *that* item with `[idnap]`.

Try something like this:

```
$count = 0;

while($eredmeny = mssql_fetch_assoc($result))
{   
$table_results  = '<tr style="color: #000e94; font-size=12" align="center" valign="middle">';
$table_results .= '<td>';
$table_results .= "<input type='checkbox' name='form[$count][id]' id='form[$count][id]' value='{$eredmeny['ID']}'>"; 
$table_results .= '</td>';
$table_results .= '<td><input type="text" name="form[$count][idnap]" id="form[$count][idnap]" value="' . $eredmeny['ID'] .'" style="width:130px;"></td>';   
$table_results .= '<td><input type="text" name="form[$count][feladat]" id="form[$count][feladat]" value="' . $eredmeny['Feladat'] .'" style="width:130px;"></DIV></td>';
$table_results .= '<td><b><input type="text" name="form[$count][hatarnap]" id="form[$count][hatarnap]" value="' . date_format(date_create($eredmeny['Hatarido_alap']), 'd') .'" style="width:20px;">nap</b>';
$table_results .= '<input type="text" name="form[$count][hatarora]" id="form[$count][hatarora]" value="' . date_format(date_create($eredmeny['Hatarido_alap']), 'H:i:s') . '" style="width:55px;"></td>';
$table_results .= '<td>' . $eredmeny['Tipusa'] . '</td>';
$table_results .= '</tr>';
echo $table_results;
$count++;
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your comment to format the text as code (prefix each line with 4 spaces) and explain a little about what you want the code to achieve? It might be worth you opening this as a new question.

Comment: Good, I find it out in recent minutes, but I've another question: How to use it in javascript, similar before: 
`code` var myControls = document.hozzaado.elements["form[][idnap]"]  if(!myControls.length) myControls = [myControls] for (var i = 0; i < myControls.length; i++) { var ertek=document.getElementById('datum1').value; myControls[i].value = myControls[i].value + ertek.slice(0,4); myControls[i].value = myControls[i].value + ertek.slice(5,7); myControls[i].value = myControls[i].value + ertek.slice(8,10); } –

Okay, thank you!